# Can Current move without potential difference?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

[image]

Consider the circuit given below, At the lower left corner of the circuit assume potential to be $0\ V$ , Now at the upper left corner current should be $9\ V$ and similarly at the upper right corner, According to Ohm's Law, as potential difference is $= 0$, there shouldn't be any flow of current, yet there exists conventional current in the circuit equal to $0.09$ Ampere , What is this fallacy?

**Please Highlight the fault in my approach.**

Comment: Upper right corner is not a seperatr entity from upper left corner. Its just drawn like that. Try to justify to yourself why that is so.

Comment: Not possible******* answer to your handline

Comment: Where does Ohm's law state about potential difference ? It only states that $V= iR$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume wires to be ideal in the circuit which have zero resistance but this is not the reality.

In fact these wires have some resistance that's why the potential difference between the upper left corner and upper right corner is not zero.

As the resistance is quite low that's why we neglect it.

Comment: Even considering ideal wires you can have current. There is nothing wrong with this mathematically. If $V=IR$ holds and if $V=0$ and $R=0$, then $I$ is allowed to be anything.

Comment: Oh! I didn't knew it. Thanks for the information